# Define a function with a condition

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I defined a function `u[y]`.

```
Λ = -30;
u[η_] := (2*η - 2*η^3 + η^4) + Λ / 6*(η - 3*η^2 + 3*η^3 - η^4);
θ = Integrate[u[η]*(1 - u[η]), {η, 0, 1}] // N;
δ = 1/θ;
u[y_] := (2*y/δ - 2*(y/δ)^3 + (y/δ)^4) + Λ/6*((y/δ) - 3*(y/δ)^2 + 3*(y/δ)^3 - (y/δ)^4);
```

For values `y / δ >1` the function has to return `u[y] = 1`.
How to define this condition?

The result of the function for `0 < y < 80` has to be like the image:

[image]

Comment: Check `Piecewise` or `Condition`. Note your code is difficult to read and could be much simplified.

Comment: How can I use greek letters in this forum in order to simplify the read? @anderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the definition (or condition) `u[y_ /; y > δ] := 1`:

```
Λ = -30;
u[η_] := (2*η - 2*η^3 + η^4) + Λ/6*(η - 3*η^2 + 3*η^3 - η^4);
θ = Integrate[u[η]*(1 - u[η]), {η, 0, 1}] // N;
δ = 1/θ;
u[y_ /; y > δ] := 1
u[y_] := (2*y/δ -2*(y/δ)^3 + (y/δ)^4) + Λ/6*((y/δ) - 3*(y/δ)^2 + 3*(y/δ)^3 - (y/δ)^4);
```

Thus:

```
Plot[u[y], {y, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You also can use `Piecewise` function to get the same plot:

```
u[y_] := Piecewise[{{1, y > δ}}, (2*y/δ - 2*(y/δ)^3 +(y/δ)^4) + Λ/6*((y/δ) - 3*(y/δ)^2 + 
  3*(y/δ)^3 - (y/δ)^4)]
```

Comment: This condition will be applied to the derivative of `u[y]` as well ?

Comment: you mean that `u'[y]=1` for $y>\delta$?

Comment: I think if you plot `u'[y]` it will not consider the condition (y>δ) for `u[y]`.
It will be plot `u'[y]` based on `u[y]`without consider the condition for `u[y]`(y>δ).

Comment: Yes, in that case, I suggest you use the definition via `Piecewise`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
u2[y_] := u[Clip[y, {-∞, δ}]]
Plot[u2[y], {y, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]